# Content Security Policy, with CDN on specific pages only, using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, cdn, content-security-policy

I'm just adding a content security policy and after much reading went with this:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "base-uri 'self'; default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src https://youtube.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline; font-src 'self'; form-action 'self'"
```

However, I forgot to factor in certain pages of the site that have CDN in place, such as the home page, contact page, policies etc. I've read some information on how to alter the content-security-policy for CDN, but it's going above my head, mainly because I understand better with examples, but the examples provided write like you're an expert and not a layman. I'm a layman.

Our CDN is set within a caching plugin, and our CDN looks something like: example.cdn.net can someone please provide an example of what I do to still have a content security policy, but accept pages that have CDN on them? At the moment the most apparent things missing from the CDN pages are the images.

Grateful for any help.

Comment: The browser console should tell you what was blocked and why.

Answer (score 0):

Browse your webpage with developer tools open. When there is a CSP related error, consider allowlisting the offending source in your CSP. E.g. if you see violations of 'img-src' (could also be with a fallback to 'default-src'), then ad that hostname to the directive. Include the directive if it is not already defined, e.g. "img-src 'self' example.cdn.net;"

If it is hard to cover all parts of your web page you can use Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only with a reporting endpoint in production to get all the violations encountered by users. But in this case you need to verify all violations as there will be some user specific violations that are not related to your site and content.

Comment: Thank for your response. Just to help understand. So to add CDN to the CSP I would just need to type example.cdn.net after 'self'? I understand I would need to do testing after this to check everything is okay.

Comment: To answer my own query, I can see it is just entering the CDN (with https) after self and with no quotes. Works perfectly. Just having some problems with CDN and plugins now, will investigate further. Thanks for help